# JavaFX ObservableArrayList no output

Tags: javafx, tableview

Im having a hard time getting an observableArrayList to print onto a TableView for JavaFX. No errors are coming up on the code and its not giving me anything specific to work with. The code will run but no output will come up. I used outprint to check and it seems to stop just before the try statement. This is my first time working with FX so any help would be appreciated.

**Application Class:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    TableView<Product> table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("List");
        Connection connection = getConnection();

        //Name column
        TableColumn<Product, String> code = new TableColumn<>("code");
        code.setMinWidth(200);
        code.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("code"));

        //Price column
        TableColumn<Product, Double> price = new TableColumn<>("Price");
        price.setMinWidth(100);
        price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

        //Quantity column
        TableColumn<Product, String> description = new TableColumn<>("description");
        description.setMinWidth(100);
        description.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
        getConnection(); 
        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getProduct());
        table.getColumns().addAll(code, description, price);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:products.sqlite";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
        return connection;
    }

    //Get all of the products
    public ObservableList<Product> getProduct(){
        String sql = "SELECT ProductCode, Description, Price "
                  + "FROM Products ORDER BY ProductCode ASC";
        ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
             PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
             ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {          
            while (rs.next()) {
                String code = rs.getString("ProductCode");
                String description = rs.getString("Description");
                double price = rs.getDouble("Price");

                Product p = new Product(code, description, price);
                products.add(p);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) { 
        }
        return products;
    }
}
```

**Product Class:**

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Product {

    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private String code;
    private String description;

    public Product(){
        this.code = "";
        this.description = "";
        this.price = 0;
    }

    public Product(String code, double price, String description){
        this.code = code;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Product(String code, String description, double price) {
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getPriceFormatted() {
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return currency.format(price);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You say no errors are coming up but it appears you are swallowing any possible `SQLException`. If a `SQLException` is thrown in your code the only effect would be returning an empty or incomplete `ObservableList`. At the very least add a `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` block and try running it again to see if any errors occur.

Comment: Also, two times you call `getConnection()` in your `start` method but never use the returned `Connection` (not even to close them); and only one time do you assign the returned `Connection` to a variable. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Added the e.printStackTrace() and got a block of error. Its telling me that my table Products does not exist. So thats progress. As for the multi connections I was thinking that the db was not connecting and was trying to provoke an error message if that was the case. At-least I know what the problem is now. Thank you